# How to specify self-installed fonts to XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, auctex, xetex

I successfully installed the font (*.tfm, *.pfb and *.vf files) of my university, I'm now struggling to use them with XeLaTeX. About my specifications:

I am running TeXLive 2011 using AucTex 11.86.

My LaTeX file looks as follow:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex-xdvipdfmx                                                                                                                                               
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode                                                                                                                                                     

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path = /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/ETH,
Extension= .pfb]
%\setmainfont{Arial}                                                                                                                                                               
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[usenames]{color}                                                                                                                                                      
\usepackage{lineno}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                                                                                                                                                     
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

% \usepackage{wrapfig}                                                                                                                                                             
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{multirow}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.35}

\title{test Xelatex}

\author{Tonkiplis}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\abstract{Abstract: only an outline for now.}

\noindent{\bf Keywords:}

\section{Introduction}
lol
\section{Methodology}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

And I tried the different extensions (tfm, pfb and vf). The compilation is successful but the output pdf only contains an empty page.

- What am I doing wrong?
- How shall I specify the font path to be successful?
- What is the meaning of those tfm, pfb and vf types?

Comment: [welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) Some of us may find it hard to provide assistance here, as your example is not functional yet. Just a few obvious things: there should at least be a `\begin{document}` somewhere; `fontspec` would be required as well; your `\setmainfont` doesn't look like you're trying to load a font *at all*. A mere path and extension won't suffice to tell `fontspec` what font it's supposed to load.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main resons to use `XeTeX` is the easy access to TrueType and OpenType fonts. It's possible to use `XeTeX` with "old" latex fonts, but if you do, you may run into some problems. Is your university's font only distributed in tfm/pfb/vf format? If they provide it in TrueType or OpenType, then simply use these. Install them according to your systems usual way of installing fonts and use them by their name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Tonkiplis if this answer helps you please consider to upvote and accept it. That is the way here to say thanks you ...